# Should parallel questions where you are the subject/object be allowed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not sure if I have the best title here, but I recently thought of a pair of questions, and I'm not sure how to pose them:

- how to make a good first impression?
- how to deal with someone who made a good first impression, but they quickly changed?

I think these two are very interrelated because they focus on each side of making a good first impression, and also because many of the ways you make a good first impression can be abused. So the first question is shaded by the second (e.g. someone did X to make a good first impression but betrayed me, and now I'm leery of doing X even though it  seems like a good idea).

So, should these questions be allowed, and if so, should they be linked together? Should they be asked at once, or should there be a wait between them? And would we use tags to notify that they reciprocate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to ask about first impressions is a good one, in my opinion. May I suggest asking these two questions in separate posts. Though they are related, they appear to be different (at least to me).

Also, each question needs to be specific enough to be addressed with a specific answer. I say this with the first bullet example in mind, mostly. That question could be the title to a book.

Personally, I would be interested in reading your posts, as well as the answers our imaginative users may have.